# Make a 3D model transparent

Tags: .net, transparent, modelvisual3d

How can I make a specific 3d model transparent? Is it as simple as changing the opacity of the model's material?

I tried the following:

```
SolidColorBrush br = (SolidColorBrush)matDif.Brush; //matDif = DiffuseMaterial
br.Opacity = 0.3;
```

When it tries setting the opacity it says that it is in a read-only state and cannot be changed?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
        Color c = new Color();
        c.A = 128;
        c.R = Colors.PeachPuff.R;
        c.G = Colors.PeachPuff.G;
        c.B = Colors.PeachPuff.B;
        Material Material = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(c));
```

works for me

Comment: Only that object looks transparent, the next object is not visible.

Answer (score 1):

On [this page](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780735623941/ch01lev1sec14) (which admittedly is XAML rather than C# it has the following:

```
<GeometryModel3D.Material>
    <DiffuseMaterial Brush="#8000FFFF" />
</GeometryModel3D.Material>

<GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
    <DiffuseMaterial Brush="#80FF0000" />
</GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
```

So it looks like you just set the Brush to an ARGB colour.

[This thread on social.msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/6d7da6bb-3b97-4e2f-9e55-f3128ceef69b) has some interesting looking links. I haven't looked at them all, but some of them might be useful.